# Python except not working when the file is executed in win cmd

Tags: python, except

can you please help me with finding an answer why except does not work in the below code when executing python script in CMD? Instead of printing defined error message, I receive standard error message.

```
from translate import Translator
translator = Translator(to_lang='de')
try:
    with open(r'C:\Users\home\PycharmProjects\FileIO\file_1.txt',mode='r') as my_file:
        transl_txt = my_file.read()
        outp = translator.translate(transl_txt)
        print(outp))
except IOError,TypeError,SyntaxError as e:
    print('smth wrng')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxQHL.png)

I was expecting to receive defined in except block error message.

Comment: There is a syntax error here `print(outp))`

Comment: Intended, as this question is about handling errors.

Comment: The program never get to actually executing as that error gets detected during byte code generation. I think the only time you are likely to be able to catch that exception is when doing something like `eval()` or `exec()`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, python creates a semi-compiled bytecode before actually running the program, and errors such as a SyntaxError are found during this process. The program returns a default error because it has bumped into the problem before assimilating the try and except method you've implemented.

Also, if you want to use except with multiple types of errors, you should write them in between parentheses (like `except (IOError,TypeError,SyntaxError) as e:`).

I hope this helps you :)